# GetItem with DynamoDB via AWS SDK Javascript

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk

I've written the following code which is using DynamoDB:

```
var qryItem = {
    TableName: 'MyTable',
    Key: {
        UserId: {
            S: '1234567'
        }
    }
};

dynamoDb.getItem(qryItem, function (error, data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(error){
        console.log(error, error.stack);
    }
});
```

The table `MyTable` has the following attributes:

- UserId (String) Primary partition key
- Name (String) Primary sort key
- email (string)

I've successfully executed a `scan` operation, but when I execute the `getItem` request above, the following error is returned:

`ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So yeah, as always, read the documentation thoroughly before passing go.

I specified a "Sort Key" when I created the table and you MUST pass this in when you perform a query and it *must* be populated in order for the validation schema to get the all clear.

So my query parameters **should** look like:

```
var qryItem = {
    TableName: 'MyTable',
    Key: {
        UserId: {
            S: '1234567'
        },
        Name: {
            S: 'John Citizen'
        }
    }
};
```